# Catalog Price Rule quantity based discount on original price

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog-price-rules, quantity

Right now I am working on Magento2 Promotion functionality.as per our client requirement we need to apply a discount on the product based on quantity(using the catalog price rule).

For that, I have reviewed the Magento features, But in default Magento, there are no options for setting the discount based on product quantity in catalog price rule.

**My Condition:-**

the promotional condition is, the product should have the particular attribute also follow the below cases to apply the discount.

Example:

**case 1:**

if the product quantity has 2+, the discount is 10% (which means the quantity > 2 or <=6 )

**case 2:**

if the product quantity has 6+, the discount is 20% (which means the quantity > 6 or <=11 )

**case 3:**

if the product quantity has 11+, the discount is 30%(which means the quantity >11)

Weather do you have any code level idea or third-party module for accomplishing this functionality means to share with us.

Thanks in advance for your idea and support.[image]

Comment: Have you done with this. any solution for this?

Comment: @AshishMadankar, unfortunately, still now we didn't get any answers, so we wrote some custom code in product detail page and achieved this functionality

Comment: your code is work with currency change ? if yes please put in comment